# Is google analytics important in my app?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store

So i paid someone to do an app for me. I tried to publish it to the app store but it got rejected because of this:

> "PLA 3.3.12. We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but
>   does not include ad functionality."

I heard Google Analytics was often the cause of this problem. I don't know if deleting this plugin will ruin my app. It's a really simple game so i don't think google analytics really matters... I just want to know if i can delete Google Analytics safely without ruining my app and what's the best way to remove a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your Google Analytics up to 3.03c if you want use GA anyway.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog

Change log says 'No changes to Google Analytics directly. GA users should note that Google Tag Manager no longer has a dependency on AdSupport.framework by default.'

related GA issue page
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=387

Comment: I mean, my game is so simple and i have no clue why i would need this plugin. Wouldn't it be easier to just remove that plugin?

Comment: Google Analytics is just 'analyzer', those plug-in doesn't modify your app functionally. if you don't need, just removes it. this will be more easier I think.

Comment: So basically the developer installed analyzer in MY app haha! Thanks for your answers.